# How to use tail -f without finish shell script?

Tags: bash, tail

I want to use tail command to watch and continue my script.
I don't want to stop whole script when I press "Ctrl+C" key.
Is there any good method?

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -f ./a.txt
echo "I want to print this line after tailing"
```

Comment: This is not a programming question -- it belongs on superuser.com

Comment: @GeorgeJempty SO does regularly field shell programming questions. Superuser.com would be biased toward system administration and operation questions, etc. Although, there can be a thin line at times.

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {
    echo "You slay me!"
}

tail -f ./a.txt
echo "I want to print this line after tailing"
```

At the point where you want to revert to default Ctrl-C behavior after the `tail -f` has completed or later, you would do this:

```
trap - INT
```

Or you could "customize" the interrupt by declaring a new trap function:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {
    echo "You slay me!"
}

function my_default_ctrl_c() {
    echo "You just interrupted me!"
    exit 1
}

tail -f ./a.txt
echo "I want to print this line after tailing"

trap my_default_ctrl_c INT
```

Here, a subsequent Ctrl-C from the keyboard will interrupt the script and give a custom message, "You just interrupted me!".

Comment: +1 You might want to add `trap - INT` following the `tail` command as well to restore the default `INT` handler.